# Do gitlab repo level commits include all the commits at its sub directories?

Tags: gitlab

I need to scope all the code merges at a fairly large code base. The code is hosted at gitlab.

At the repo level, I clicked "History" and I can see the commit history. Then I changed to a sub directory, clicked "History", it is a shorter list; I checked several commits of the sub directory and they are also in the repo level commit history.

Can I safely assume that all commits at sub directories are included in the repo level commits? If so, I will only check the repo level commits.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I safely assume that all commits at sub directories are included in the repo level commits

Yes: it is the equivalent of `git log -- aSubDirectory`: it filters the list of repository commit to display only the ones whose changes involved files in `aSubDirectory`.